# Construct LDFLAGS from list of full library paths in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to construct my linker flags `LDFLAGS` from a list of libraries with their full paths. Here's where/why I'm stuck. (The library names are Linux style, but that shouldn't really matter for how to solve this, I think.)

```
FULL_LIBS = \
    ./path1/libone.a \
    ../../path2/libtwo.a
# etc.    

LIB_DIRS = $(dir $(FULL_LIBS))
LIB_NAMES = $(basename $(notdir $(FULL_LIBS)))
LIB_NAMES_TRIMMED = # zzz trim leading "lib" somehow??? This is what I don't know how to do, or at least the best way

LDFLAGS += \
    $(addprefix -L, $(LIB_DIRS)) \
    $(addprefix -l, $(LIB_NAMES_TRIMMED))
```

The desired result, if it's not obvious, should be like

`LDFLAGS += -L./path1 -L../../path2 -lone -ltwo`

Not sure if I *NEED* regular expressions (or `sed`/`awk`/`grep`), so I'll withhold that tag ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)) for now.

Comment: Not sure my `-L`/`-l` ordering is right, as I believe I recall it must be in a particular order, but don't worry, I can probably figure that part out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the text processing capabilities of make (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) :

```
LIB_NAMES_TRIMMED = $(subst lib,,$(LIB_NAMES))
```

Although this could fail if the string "lib" appears elsewhere in the library names. To avoid that we can use 2 steps:

```
LIB_NAMES_TRIMMED = $(basename $(notdir $(subst /lib,/,$(FULL_LIBS))))
```

As explained by Matt, it's even simpler with patsubst:

```
LIB_NAMES_TRIMMED = $(patsubst lib%,%,$(LIB_NAMES))
```

Comment: Simply `$(patsubst lib%,%,$(LIB_NAMES))` is enough.

Comment: Oh right, `subst` is what I couldn't remember if something like that existed. Great for simple find-replace. I figured there had to be an easier way than `sed`...!